# How do I convert a jQuery Date value to a long value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery Date function which shows output like `July 09 2012`. Now I want to change this string value to a long value like `1335363564815`, e.g. milliseconds. How can I do this?

This is my code for my calender:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $('#date2').jdPicker({date_format:"FF dd YYYY"}); 
</script>
```

I use this plugin: [`jquery.jdpicker.js`](http://jdpicker.paulds.fr/?p=doc)

Comment: By "long value" do you mean a timestamp, like you get from the `.getTime()` method of Date instances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
var milliseconds  = Date.parse($('#date2').val());
```

[As docs says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> Parses a string representation of a JavaScript date, and returns the number of milliseconds

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1380/)